# How to listen for contract creation, or all block events?

Tags: web3js, events, constructor

I'm building a web app with web3 where users can deploy a certain contract and assign some people to it. Inside the constructor of that contract I also output a certain event. I want these assigned people to get notified when something like this happens, but so far, I haven't found anything.

So my question is, is it possible to somehow listen for contract creation events in general, or better yet, a custom event emitted from any new contract?

Comment: if you using web3 to deploy a contract it will return back address of that contract all you have to do is listen to it

Comment: That doesn't work because I have 2 separate users that are not on the same machine

Comment: Maybe in your contract creation method emit an event saying that a contract has been created and listen to it on your frontend using ```EMITEVENT.watch()```